# Windows XP doesn't recognize iPhone as a camera

Tags: windows-xp, iphone, photos, camera

My iPhone 3GS doesn´t show up in the Scanners and Cameras tool or in My Computer when I connect it via USB to Windows XP. Nor does the Camera Wizard pop up. iTunes does recognize the device, but it doesn't offer a way to synchronize photos.

How do I make Windows XP detect the device as a Camera? I currently have no way of downloading photos from the iPhone to my computer.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your iPhone should show up in *My Computer*. Drill down to the XXXApple folder(s) and copy your photos from there. If you need photo syncing, you can try something like **[Microsoft SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52&displaylang=en)**.

Comment: No, it doesn't show up in My Computer. I guess that's part of the problem although iTunes does recognize it.